# R In SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server-2016

I've recently downloaded the CTP for SQL Server 2016 in order to get a grasp with the integration of the R language with SQL Server.

I haven't been able to find any resources/documentation on the topic as of yet.

Has anyone else had any joy with it?

Thanks

Comment: While it's certainly annoying, such broad requests for documentation are off-topic on StackOverflow. These requests cannot have a definitive answer. CTP versions especially do not represent a mature technology and their documentation will be in a state of flux.

Answer (score 4):

I've been researching this as well and here are my findings.

**As of 2015-08-19**

- During Microsoft Ignite conference (2015), Lindsey Allen demo'd R integration in the new SQL Server 2016. [Link](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK2558)
- The feature is not yet ready in [CTP](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-sql-server-2016) 2. This is discussed [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/65107366-d02d-491f-8e6f-739530b8e563/using-r-in-sql-server-2016-ctp2?forum=sqldatabaseengine).
- Books online for SQL Server 2016 [Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214%28v=sql.130%29.aspx)

Please update me with any new information you come across!! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

R is available on SQL Server 2016 CTP 3.

Comment: Is this true for **all** versions of R (RRO as well as the 'standard' R) or exclusively for the commercial R entrerprise version?